# Add clickable buttons to telegram-bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I'm developing a simple telegram bot with node.js telegram-bot.
https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api
For now I want user to stop typing messages (with letters), just pressing one of a few buttons. And when he clicks on the button, his telegram's client has to send back to my bot another message (something like "clicked yes" or "clicked no").
I've found that it can be made with

```
var options = {
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        inline_keyboard: [
          [{ text: 'Some button text 1', callback_data: '1' }],
          [{ text: 'Some button text 2', callback_data: '2' }],
          [{ text: 'Some button text 3', callback_data: '3' }]
        ]
      })
    };
bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "answer.", option);
```

So user receives 3 kind of messages, and when he clicks them, he doesn't send me back anything.
I need another type of buttons (which will be in the bottom of client's app).

Comment: you need to listen for `callback_query` .. https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/0174b875ff69f6750fc80a049315c9a0d7a5e471/examples/polling.js#L61

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to listen for the `callback_query` .. As outlined :

```
bot.on('callback_query', function onCallbackQuery(callbackQuery) {
  const action = callbackQuery.data;
  const msg = callbackQuery.message;
  const opts = {
    chat_id: msg.chat.id,
    message_id: msg.message_id,
  };
  let text;

  if (action === '1') {
    text = 'You hit button 1';
  }

  bot.editMessageText(text, opts);
});
```

More info can be found in the library itself. : https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/0174b875ff69f6750fc80a049315c9a0d7a5e471/examples/polling.js#L78

Some further reading indicates : https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery

> TelegramBot emits callback_query when receives a Callback Query

This relates to this documentation here : https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery

If the button was attached to a message sent via the bot (in inline mode), the field `inline_message_id` will be present.

Exactly one of the fields `data` or `game_short_name` will be present.

Comment: worked perfectly for me. thank you. can you please also explain how to make custom buttons(which are in the bottom of the telegram app screen), if you know?

Comment: @Kamiky I'm actually not too sure if you can access the native layer, but maybe `one_time_keyboard` would be something you could use ? https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup It's refered to as a custom keyboard.. Here also : https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards

Answer (score 4):

You are using inline keyboard, instead you can try reply keyboard markup which appears in the bottom of telegram screen as you said.

It is implemented easily and you can find some useful information about it [here](https://irazasyed.github.io/telegram-bot-sdk/usage/keyboards/) and [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards).

Answer (score 1):

I've used `telegraf` library while working on `telegram-bot`, most of the libraries are same so you can consider it for reference.

You will get `callback_data` as an input when user click on the button

```
await bot.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, "Please click on button below.", {
    reply_markup: {
        inline_keyboard: [
            [   
                {
                    text: "Yes",
                    callback_data: "btn_yes"
                },
                {
                    text: "No",
                    callback_data: "btn_no"
                },
               
            ]
        ]
    }
});
```